# define the file by the content in it

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a way to determine if a file is really the one that is needed by the content in it.

Files for the example secure and messages.

**/var/log/secure**

```
Oct 27 06:45:32 host sshd[16609]: Accepted publickey for username from 11.22.33.1 port 57870 ssh2: RSA SHA256:XXXXXX 
Oct 27 06:45:32 host sshd[16609]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0) 
Oct 27 06:45:46 host sudo: username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
```

**/var/log/messages**

```
Oct 27 03:51:01 host systemd: Started Session 1000 of user root.
Oct 27 03:51:01 host systemd: Starting Session 1000 of user root.
Oct 27 03:54:01 host systemd: Started Session 1001 of user root.
```

Is it possible to find out that the file *secure* is really *secure* or *messages* is really *messages*?

Perhaps it makes sense to define a file by keywords

```
filename = "/var/log/messages"
message_words = ["systemd", "kernel", "freshclam"]
if File.file?(filename) then
  File.open(filename, 'r') { |f| @w = f.read() }
  message_words.each do |x|
    puts "pass" if @w.include?(x)
  end
end
```

Or there is a way to do it for some template?

Comment: _"match a particular pattern"_ – which pattern?

Comment: Yes. Regular expressions are a good place to start for any question that contains the phrase "match a particular pattern".

Comment: If it were always at the first line it could be

    `if File.open(my_log_file, 'r').readline['host systemd:']
      # rest of your code
    end`

If not and your log files are big you don't want to read the whole file just to check for the first occurance of this string. You would rather lazy read the file until the string is found.

    `if File.open(my_log_file, 'r').each_line.any? {|line| line['host systemd:']}
      # rest of your code
    end`

Answer (score 1):

```
File.open('file.txt').read =~ PATTERN
```

where `PATTERN` is an instance of `Regexp`. You can use `//` to specify the pattern. So e.g.:

```
File.open('file.txt').read =~ /foo|bar/
```

Would return a non-nil value only if the file contents had `"foo"` or `"bar"` in it.